# Using groupby and duplicate in pandas

Tags: python, r, pandas, duplicates, data-science

I am trying to translate an R dplyr code into Python Pandas and I am not getting similar results when using `groupby()` and `duplicate()`.

I have a dataset of size (20000*3), as follows:

| Product | Trade | Crop |
| --- | --- | --- |
| Fungi | VIC | Grapes |
| ASH | CAN | APPLE |
| FUNGI | CAN | SEED |

In R, they have written the code as follows:

```
Products_table <- Products_table %>% group_by(product,crop) %>% filter(! duplicated(trade))}
```

They get a reduced dataset as output with (5000*3) size. I think the duplicated values were deleted.

I've tried the same thing in Python Pandas:

```
 product_table = product_table.groupby(['product','crop']).reset_index(drop=False)
```

But I am getting a table of size (n*1), which has reduced the column size.

Any suggestions to how do I get to the `groupby` and `duplicated` in Python Pandas and get the same result as in R dplyr?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can simply use the `drop_duplicates` function as follows:

```
product_table.drop_duplicates(subset=['product','crop'], inplace=True, ignore_index=True)
```

Comment: correction : `subset=['product','crop','trade']`

Comment: @Shijith As per the question, he's intending to drop duplicates in these columns only

Answer (score 0):

You can do it the same way you did in R using [`datar`](https://github.com/pwwang/datar):

```py
>>> from datar.all import f, tribble, duplicated, distinct, group_by, filter
>>> 
>>> df = tribble(
...     f.product, f.trade, f.crop,
...     "Fungi",   "VIC",   "Grapes",
...     "ASH",     "CAN",   "APPLE",
...     "FUNGI",   "CAN",   "SEED",
...     "FUNGI",   "CAN",   "SEED",
... )
>>> 
>>> df >> group_by(f.product, f.crop) >> filter(~duplicated(f.trade))
   product    trade     crop
  <object> <object> <object>
0    Fungi      VIC   Grapes
1      ASH      CAN    APPLE
2    FUNGI      CAN     SEED

[Groups: product, crop (n=3)]
```

But what you are look for is actually `distinct`:

```py
>>> df >> group_by(f.product, f.crop) >> distinct(f.trade)
   product    trade     crop
  <object> <object> <object>
0      ASH      CAN    APPLE
1    FUNGI      CAN     SEED
2    Fungi      VIC   Grapes

[Groups: product, crop (n=3)]
```